# How to run Python script to send data to Google PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

From Google Console, I am creating a topic and publishing it and it is working fine. Now I want to do it from a Python script, which I have done but I don't know where to put those files in Google Pub/Sub.

Can someone please teach me how can I accomplish it by using a script? I am new and I am student. I have never used Google Pub/Sub. I just want to make some random data and send it to Pub/Sub that's all I want.

Someone told me I need web hosting to run those scripts, is it true? Please guide me briefly. For 3 days I've been reading docs and now everything is now messed up in my mind. In advance thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only doc you need to follow is the [Pub/Sub quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries). The "web hosting" you need is having a GCP project, nothing else.

You can do this quickstart from the [GCP Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quickstart) itself, creating the files with `nano` or `vim`. Just remember to set `project_id`, `topic_name` and `subscription_name` in the scripts.

Comment: so you are saying i have to use http protocol ? do i really need a backend script to run a script ?

Comment: @rimsha what you need is in the [Pub/Sub quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries). It's the minimal setup to use Pub/Sub using Python scripts. Follow it and run your scripts from the shell with `python your-script.py`

Comment: omg quickstart has many things which one i should use plz guide me uncle i will be so thankful

Answer (score 1):

as rightly stated by Guillermo Cacheda all you need is PUB/SUB QuickStart.

However, Firstly you will need a project which is deployed on GCP(Google Cloud Platform).
Let's say you have a project and you know the project_ID.
You need to install the google-cloud-pubsub using pip.

/*ensure that you are using virtualenv as described in the python dev setup guide*/

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-pubsub
```

/*Create a Topic to which you can publish or subscribe.*/

```
gcloud pubsub topics create my-topic
```

/*to Publish Message*/

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
```

/*TODO project_id = "Your Google Cloud Project ID"
TODO topic_name = "Your Pub/Sub topic name"*/

```
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
```

/*The `topic_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
in the form `projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_name}`*/

```
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)

for n in range(1, 10):
    data = u"Message number {}".format(n)
    # Data must be a bytestring
    data = data.encode("utf-8")
    # When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data)
    print(future.result())

print("Published messages.")
```

/*to receive Messages*/

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
```

/*TODO project_id = "Your Google Cloud Project ID" , TODO subscription_name = "Your Pub/Sub subscription name", TODO timeout = 5.0  # "How long the subscriber should listen for messages in seconds"*/

```
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
```

/*The `subscription_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
in the form `projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{subscription_name}`*/

```
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
    project_id, subscription_name
)

def callback(message):
    print("Received message: {}".format(message))
    message.ack()

streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(
    subscription_path, callback=callback
)
print("Listening for messages on {}..\n".format(subscription_path))
```

/*result() in a future will block indefinitely if `timeout` is not set,
unless an exception is encountered first.*/
    try:
        streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)
    except: 
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()

/*In the end to avoid incurring charges to your GCP account for the resources, use the below command to delete the topic and subscription*/

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions delete my-sub
gcloud pubsub topics delete my-topic
```

/*Note the Above code is from the GCP docs Quickstart-client-libraries for python.*/